# Renaming dll (TBB + OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, tbb

I have built OpenCV (dynamic libs) with TBB support using CMake and VS2010. However, for the integration of my plugin (that uses opencv calls) in an external host application, i have to rename the tbb.dll, since the host application already includes a tbb.dll but using a different version.

I read that DUMPBIN and LIB commands can be used to obtain the list of export symbols for the dll to create an import library. However, according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313/en-us this is only possible for export functions using a C interface, but the Dependency Walker shows that both C and C++ interfaces are used.

So, is there a "simple" solution to rename the tbb.dll afterwards (i.e. after OpenCV was compiled)? Or do you have any hints how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to rename the DLL? What bad things happen if you don't? Just the fact that the application already ships TBB does not automatically mean that your plugin will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a nice solution, but it is possible to patch dll-s! Eg. replace any reference to tbb.dll in a dll to tbc.dll. You can just use a hex editor for this, or write a script.